# How to get the fields searched by when search button clicked in Blazor

Tags: razor, blazor

I have a search form that has controls that are coded like this:

```
<div>
   <label class="labelclass">Name</label>
   <input class=@(IsFieldInvalid("Name") ? "form-control text-uppercase is-invalid":"form-control text-uppercase") data-testid="name" @bind="Data.Name">
```

....

What I need to do is list each control if it is used at the bottom of the page like so:

> You selected: Name, Address, Phone Number ...

After a button is clicked so on the onclick() of the button

I am pretty new to Blazor so I am not sure even where to start with this

I was thinking that I could use the @bind to create the list but I would rather not loop through all of the controls.

CLARIFICATION:  I would like to get the name of the control and return it to a list but only if it is filled in the search.  For example:

```
<input type="text" id="txtOne"></input>
```

Would produce:

> You selected: txtOne

Comment: What do you mean with 'if it is used'?

Comment: @user13256346 I should have been more clear.  I just meant if the control is used on the page.  I only showed one control but there are several on the page.  If the control isn't used I don't want it to show in the listing

Comment: Blazor is single page application (SPA), this mean you don't POST the form. Search about data binding and a good start is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @RemiTHOMAS thank you I think that would be a good start.  I appreciate all the help